# Can I guarantee that Sleep() would not sleep for more than 10 ms?

Tags: c++, winapi, sleep

I know that `Sleep()` is not accurate, but is there's a way to make it not sleep for more than 10 ms (i.e. only sleep between 1 ms and 10 ms)? Or does `Sleep(1)` already guarantee that?

Comment: Even in the absence of `Sleep`, you can't really guarantee that there won't be a 10ms gap between two successive operations (since your thread might get preempted in the middle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want guaranteed timings, you will not be using Windows at all.

To answer your question, `Sleep()` does not provide any means of guaranteeing an upper bound on the sleep time.

In windows, this is because `Sleep()` relinquishes the threads's time slice, and it is not guaranteed that the system scheduler will schedule the sleeping thread (i.e. allocate another time slice) to execute immediately after the sleep time is up.   That depends on priorities of competing threads, scheduling policies, and things like that.

In practice, the actual sleep interval depends a lot on what other programs are running on the system, configuration of the system, whether other programs are accessing slow drives, etc etc.

With a lightly loaded system, it is a fair bet `Sleep(1)` will sleep between 1 and 2 ms on any modern (GHz frequency CPU or better).   However, it is not impossible for your program to experience greater delays.

With a heavily loaded system (lots of other programs executing, using CPU and timer resources), it is a fair bet your program will experience substantially greater delays than 1ms, and even more than 10ms.

In short:  no guarantees.

Comment: [Windows CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) is a real-time OS. If you need deterministic interrupt latency you may be using Windows after all.

Comment: Windows CE is what is sometimes called a soft realtime system - failure to meet deadlines affects quality of service.  It is not a hard realtime system, in which failure to meet deadlines represents a complete failure of affected subsystems (and/or the system).   It is hard realtime systems that require timing guarantees, not soft realtime systems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee it.

This is what [real time OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) are for.

In general case if your OS doesn't experience high loads sleep will be pretty accurate but as you increase load on it the more inaccurate it will get.

Answer (score 1):

***No.*** *Or, yes, depending on your perspective.*

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx):

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If
>   you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder
>   of its time slice but remain ready. Note that a ready thread is not
>   guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run
>   until some time after the sleep interval elapses. For more
>   information, see [Scheduling Priorities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx).

**What this means is that the problem isn't `Sleep`. Rather, when `Sleep` ends, your thread may still need to wait to become active again.**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot count on 10 milliseconds, that's too low.  Sleep() accuracy is affected by:

- The clock tick interrupt frequency.  In general, the processor tends to be in a quiescent state, not consuming any power and turned off by the HLT instruction.  It is dead to the world, unaware that time is passing and unaware that your sleep interval has expired.  A periodic hardware interrupt generated by the chipset wakes it up and makes it pay attention again.  By default, this interrupt is generated 64 times per second.  Or once every 15.625 milliseconds.
- The thread scheduler runs at every clock interrupt.  It is the one that notices that your sleep interval has expired, it will put the thread back into the ready-to-run state.  And boosts its priority so that it is more likely to acquire a processor core.  It will do so when no other threads with higher priority are ready to run.

There isn't much you can do about the 2nd bullet, you have to compete with everybody else and take your fair share.  If the thread does a lot of sleeping and little computation then it is not unreasonable to claim more than your fair share, call [SetThreadPriority()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to boost your base priority and make it more likely that your sleep interval is accurate.  If that isn't good enough then the only way to claim a high enough priority that will always beat everybody else is by writing ring 0 code, a driver.

You can mess with the 1st bullet, it is pretty common to do so.  Also the reason why many programmers think that the default accuracy is 10 msec.  Or if they use Chrome that it might be 1 msec, that browser jacks up the interrupt rate sky-high.  A fairly unreasonable thing to do, bad for power consumption, unless you are in the business of making your mobile operating system products look good :)

Call [timeBeginPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you need to make your sleep intervals short enough,  timeEndPeriod() when you're done.  Use NtSetTimerResolution() if you need to go lower than 1 msec.

Answer (score 0):

`Sleep` won't guarantee that.

The only way I know of doing that is to have a thread wait for a fast timer event and free a synchronization object every 10 ms or so.

You will pass a semaphore to this "wait server task", and it will free it on the next timer tick, thus giving you a response time between 0 and 10 ms.

Of couse if you want an extreme precision you will have to boost this thread priority above other tasks that might preempt it, and at any rate you might still be preempted by system processes and/or interrupt handlers, which will add some noise to your timer.